# Error in Heroku-apps: Invalid left-hand side assignment

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, bitbucket, heroku-toolbelt

Please I am new to heroku.

I installed Github git and heroku-toolbet on my local machine.

After successful sign up on Github and heroku.
I wanted to start another project but this time I am using bitbucket as my repo.
After I created a simple rails project, I could not deploy to heroku. Each time attempt run 
   "heroku create"
I got the error :
Error in heroku-apps:
 !   Invalid left-hand side in assignment
I checked the error log and i noticed a reference to github in a directory: /Users/jdickey/src/github.com/heroku/cli/cli.go

and my codes are on bitbucket.
Please could this be the problem or what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. I deleted all the content within error.log and restarted the console and that fixed it.

Comment: It would help if you add a terminal example in a code block. Short answers tend to get voted down.

Answer (score 0):

I retried deploying the app to heroku with bitbucket repo after leaving the project for a day and it was successful.
I will still like to know what went wrong anyway